# Angular Material - mat-select : Custom padding overflows parent element

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material components, and I am trying to customise a combo-box (select). When I change the padding of the component, it overflows the wrapper div element. I was expecting it to grow along.

*Look and feel **before** adding padding*

[image]

*Look and feel **after** adding padding*
[image]

As we can see the mat-select div did not grew as the the mat-select element increase its width by adding padding

**html code**

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; min-width: 100px; margin: 0px 5px; float: left">
    <mat-form-field class="my-select template-select">
        <mat-select [(value)]="templateSelected">
            <mat-select-trigger>
                <div fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                    <i fxFlex="none" class="material-icons md-dark">visibility</i>
                    <span fxFlex>{{templateSelected}}</span>
                </div>
            </mat-select-trigger>
            <mat-option value="Full data">
                <div fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="template-option">
                    <i fxFlex="none" class="material-icons md-dark">done</i>
                    <span fxFlex>Full data</span>
                </div>
            </mat-option>
            <mat-option value="My quarterly report">
                <div fxLayoutAlign="start center" class="templateOption">
                    <i fxFlex="24px" class="material-icons md-dark"></i>
                    <span fxFlex>My quarterly report</span>
                </div>
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid black; min-width: 100px; margin-right: 5px; float: left">
    <button class="toolbar-button" mat-stroked-button>FILTER</button>
</div>
```

I am changing the padding on the mat-select element as you can see below. (perhaps is not the place to change it)

**css code**

```
.my-select mat-select {
    background-color: rgba(58, 40, 8, 0.12);
    /*padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;*/ /* NO Left and right padding*/
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;   /* 10px left and right padding*/

    border-radius: 5px;
}

.my-select .mat-select-value {
    font-family: Roboto-Regular;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: rgba(58, 40, 8, 0.87);
}

.my-select .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
}

.my-select mat-select-trigger div>i {
    margin-right: 8px;
}
```

Does anyone understand why this behaviour? How can I fix it?

Live code available: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-overflow

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards

Comment: A [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/) of your problem may be useful.

Comment: Thank you, i never used it before. https://angular-mat-select-overflow.stackblitz.io

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-overflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think here you need to use `box-sizing: border-box;` With the CSS `box-sizing` Property. The box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height.

**style.css**

```
/* Add application styles & imports to this file! */
.my-select mat-select {
    background-color: rgba(58, 40, 8, 0.12);
    /*padding: 6px 0px 6px 0px;*/ /* NO Left and right padding*/
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;   /* 10px left and right padding*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

**[Forked solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-overflow-bzs2yz?file=src%2Fstyles.css)**

Comment: You are the man! It worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Have a great day